# Hello Folks: I am having problem in starting sails app in nodejs. can anyone put forth their insights on that?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-postgresql

I tried running the latest version of node and postgresql, but was having problem i deprecated node to 13.12.0 and sails-postgresql to 1.0.2 as mentioned in one of the blog. still the error is coming. Stack trace is as below:

sails lift

info: Starting app...

(node:10460) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
info: Initializing `apianalytics` hook...  (requests to monitored routes will be logged!)
info: ·• Auto-migrating...  (alter)
info:    Hold tight, this could take a moment.
error:
error: Error: Sails is taking too long to load.

---

---

Troubleshooting tips:
-• Were you still reading/responding to an interactive prompt?
(Whoops, sorry!  Please lift again and try to respond a bit more quickly.)

-• Do you have a lot of stuff in `assets/`?  Grunt might still be running.
(Try increasing the hook timeout.  Currently it is 40000.
e.g. `sails lift --hookTimeout=80000`)

-• Is `blueprints` a custom or 3rd party hook?
(*If* `initialize()` is using a callback, make sure it's being called.)

---

---

```
at Timeout.tooLong [as _onTimeout] (C:\Users\dearm\OneDrive\Desktop\my work\sails-logrocket\myapp\node_modules\sails\lib\app\private\loadHooks.js:191:21)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

error: Could not load Sails app.
error:
error: Tips:
error:  • First, take a look at the error message above.
error:  • Make sure you've installed dependencies with `npm  install`.
error:  • Check that this app was built for a compatible version of Sails.
error:  • Have a question or need help?  (http://sailsjs.com/support)

complete code is here https://github.com/mannawar/sails_app

Answer (score 1):

Try using Node version 10 and sails-postgresql version 2.0.0